# How to inspect and debug the MAUI hybrid blazor webview on Android?

Tags: android, maui, maui-blazor

Prior to the latest release candidate (RC1) I was able to inspect and debug the android blazor webview using chrome, by navigating to [chrome://inspect/#devices](https://chrome://inspect/#devices). However, after updating, the chrome tools no longer shows the blazor/maui webview. Is it possible to re-enable this feature?

[image]

Comment: Here is a detailed answer for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/72652029/256925

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blazor web view deveoper tools must now be added as a service. See the [maui documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/developer-tools?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=android)

```
#if DEBUG
    builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
#endif
```