# MAUI blazor an unhandled error has occurred

Tags: blazor, maui-blazor

If there is an error in the program, I get "An unhandled error has occured".
With Blazor Web assembly I can open the developper tools in the browser to get the details of what happend. This is not possible in Blazor MAUI.

So how can I get the details of the error in Blazor MAUI?

Comment: Just use F12 to open the dev tools.

Comment: F12 has no effect

Comment: What operating system? It works on my Blazor Maui apps. click in the window, then press F12

Answer (score 15):

There is a way to "remotely inspect" your app using the browser developer tool (F12). First, check if you added the AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools in your `MauiProgram.cs`

```
#if DEBUG
    builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
#endif
```

Run your App and open a new tab in your browser (outside the emulator) and type:

- For Chrome: chrome://inspect
- For Edge: edge://inspect

Wait a little and you will see an "inspect" button like below:
[image]

And you can even navigate in your App from there:
[image]

Comment: and how would you go about doing this if the app was in debug on a physical android device connected via usb ?

Answer (score 7):

When you get this type of error:

[image: Pic of Error]

First click the screen with your mouse, then hit F12.
Then select the Console link a top of Dev Tools Form.

[image: Dev Tools Pic]

Comment: This is the right & simplest answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can open the developer tools by pressing `ctrl + shift + i` (or `cmd + shift + i` for Mac) when you have focus inside the web view.

**Note:** you need to enable the developer tools.

```csharp
builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

// enable the developer tools
builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
builder.Services.AddBlazorWebView();
```

Comment: This does not work in MAUI.

Comment: it does for me. I am using it right now. you may need to add the tools, I will update my answer with this information.

Comment: @Cody but I need to debug this on an iOS and android device

Comment: @YaRmgl this solution will work when using a simulator...not sure how debugging works with real devices to be honest. Haven't messed with this in a while.

Comment: Also does not work for me when running a MacCatalyst app (using Visual Studio for Mac 17.5.6)