# How to inspect and debug the webview on Android for app created using MAUI?

Tags: android, maui

In my .Net MAUI app (not Blazor app) I have a `WebView` control in which I am rendering html pages generated at runtime (epub book pages), and it has lot of JavaScript code.

I need to inspect the `WebView` and access the debugger tools, to debug any issues with JS, etc.

For UWP apps, I used to use this https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9MZBFRMZ0MNJ?hl=en-us&gl=us

I am looking for something similar for Android using MAUI.

I found a similar question, but it's for Blazor app and `builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools()` does not work on MAUI app.

[How to inspect and debug the MAUI hybrid blazor webview on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71919608/how-to-inspect-and-debug-the-maui-hybrid-blazor-webview-on-android)

[MAUI blazor an unhandled error has occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71991692/maui-blazor-an-unhandled-error-has-occurred/72652029#72652029)

Comment: You can check this [Remotely debug Android WebViews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/remote-debugging/webviews).

Answer (score 3):

For android and MAUI Blazor.

Open Chrome while your app is running using url: **chrome://inspect/#devices**.

Find your device and start debugging. You have access to JS there.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xoklc.png)